# EWS: How to Edit/Update an existing Appointment?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I created some Appointments in VB.NET with EWA. It works fine. Now i want to edit the appointment ( date or topic).

for every booking I saved the booking ID in a extended property from the appointment

```
  ' Create a definition for the extended property.
            Dim extendedPropertyDefinition As New EWS.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(EWS.DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Appointment, EWS.MapiPropertyType.String)
' Add the extended property to an e-mail message object named "appointment".
            appointment.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, buchungId)
```

How can I select a appointment with the correct bookingid and edit the topic for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can search by items with the Extended property. Your code may look like this (hope c#-Code helps you too, I'm a bit out of practise in VB):

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition prop = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, <Name>, MapiPropertyType.String);

SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(prop, "SearchValue");

FolderId folder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox)

FindItemsResults<Item> result = service.FindItems(folder, filter, new ItemView(10));
```

If your "buchungid" is unique, `result.Items` should have one item if it's in the inbox.